# Are Muslims technically at war with Christians and Jews?

Tags: christianity, war, jews

In [Is Islam Luring the Christian Church Into Denying Jesus? Converted Imam Answers](http://www.christianpost.com/news/islam-luring-christian-church-denying-jesus-converted-imam-179230/), Samuel Smith, we have the following:

> [Dr. Mark Christian](http://globalfaithinstitute.org/blog-authors/author-dr-mark-christian/), a former prominent Muslim from Egypt whose great uncle was a co-founder of Muslim brotherhood and is now a Christian lecturer with the goal of warning people about the impact of Islam on the world today, conducted a webinar on March 21 titled "Is Islam Luring the American Church Into Denying Jesus?"
>
> ...
>
> Christian asserted that Muhammad died before he could formally end the war against Christians and Jews, meaning that, according to Islam, Muslims have a standing war against Christians and Jews.

It sounds like Islamophobic nonsense to me, but there might some treaty or something that he's referring to that I'm unaware of.  Also, it looks like Dr. Christian has some knowledge (maybe [a little knowledge](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/a_little_knowledge_is_a_dangerous_thing)) of Islam.

If so, it must be a technicality, as Muslims, Jews, and Christians coexist peacefully in most places throughout the world.  And the places where there's not peace, virtually everyone seems to want peace.

**Question**: Are Muslims technically at war with Christians and Jews?

Comment: "Christian asserted that Muhammad died before he could formally end the war against Christians and Jews, meaning that, according to Islam, Muslims have a standing war against Christians and Jews." The implicit assumption in that statement is that no ruler after Muhammad could have made such a treaty, or at least that no one did. The claim that no one could have due to a lack of authority would be a legal question, the claim that no one did a historical one. Which one were you hoping to get an answer to?

Comment: Its not clear what action of the Prophet is being referred to. War is against political entities and not against religions or races. While The Prophet was at war with some Jewish tribes, he had treaties of alliance or client-ship with others. In 631 CE hostilities started with the Byzantine empire and not Christianity, the Prophet simultaneously had treaties of peace with Christian Najran.

Comment: " Are Muslims technically at war with Christians and Jews?" NO. Does that answer your question? I'm not sure if this really is a good question. Any person can come and say Islam is this Islam is that. I don't think we're here to answer those. You already know the answer so I'm kinda baffled why/what you're asking. Do you want us to give resources of how there was love between Muslims and Christians? Or why there were some wars? If yes then maybe an edit is needed for your question.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones I am sorry, but I don't get your question. Do you want to know whether all the wars that happened during the time of the prophet (pbuh) with the Christians/Jews has ended or not?

Comment: @Casanova: there's going to be an ounce of truth to Christian's claim; I'm wondering what he's alluding to.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones Probably the war with the Byzantines(Rome). The article mentions  a letter to [Heraclius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heraclius), it also mentions the year 630 CE, Battle of [Mautah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Mu%27tah) occured in 629 CE, Tabuk expedition occured in 631 CE and the prophet had prepared to send another expedition before his death. There are also quotes in Seerah where the Prophet tells that he was promised the palace of Caesar and the city of Constantinople.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the core of this question is what was the intent of the Prophet when he sent letters and emissaries to the various kingdoms including the Roman Empire which was Christian at that time. Was he calling on them to accept Islam as a religion (in simply becoming Muslim), or was he calling on them to allow Islam as a religion to be propagated in their lands, or was he calling on them to accept his political authority (ie the political authority of Islam). Yasir Qadhi discusses the letters briefly in [this episode](https://youtu.be/OelPo4Gkj94?list=PLC89682017B43845D) of his seerah class, but it is not clear to me what the actual intent is. The call seems to be "aslim, taslim" (which could be submit and be safe, or become Muslim and be safe). Allah (swt) Knows best, I am not a scholar so I will not try to answer.

In my humble opinion, I think the scholars should look at the answer to this question not only from a purely textual (legal) and historical point of view, but also where Islam is in the world today and how the world is today (a world very different from that of the Prophet).

The ultimate goal of Islam is not to make war with anyone, but to call all mankind to submission to the One True God, to His Worship and the Peace which comes from that. Given that today it is possible to call the people freely to that (because of the religious freedom in most Western countries), I personally see no reason for war. Allah Knows best.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question; it is unclear on what treaties Muhammad made, and it doesn't talk about whether any of those treaties can be or were superseded by treaties that rulers after him signed.